# Explicit intents, implicit intents, and broadcasts

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to better understand the topic of intents.

An explicit intent is configured with a component's name. In every example I've seen, it's used to start or stop the component. Is this the only purpose of an explicit intent?

An implicit intent doesn't have a target component. Implicit intents can also start/stop a component, but they can also be received by BroadcastReceivers. Is there another way to receive an implicit intent?

When the OS sends the intent with the action set to Action.MAIN, that's an explicit intent, right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the android documentation:

> Explicit intents specify the component to start by name (the
>   fully-qualified class name). You'll typically use an explicit intent
>   to start a component in your own app, because you know the class name
>   of the activity or service you want to start. For example, start a new
>   activity in response to a user action or start a service to download a
>   file in the background.
>
> Implicit intents do not name a specific component, but instead declare
>   a general action to perform, which allows a component from another app
>   to handle it. For example, if you want to show the user a location on
>   a map, you can use an implicit intent to request that another capable
>   app show a specified location on a map.

Explicit intents, as you've said, are used to start an activity in your application -- or to transition from one "screen" to another.  An explicit intent would be something like `Intent intent = new Intent(currentContext, ActivityB.class);`  These types of intents are used when you are within your application and explicitly know which component you want to start depending on how the user interacts with your activity.

Implicit Intents don't directly specify the Android components which should be called, but rather just specify a general action to be performed.  These are generally used when you would like some external application to do something for you.  An example of an implicit intent used to send an email using an external application would be:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("message/rfc822");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL  , new String[]{"someemail@gmail.com"});
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "subject");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT   , "body");
```

This intent would query for applications installed on the device that can handle sending an email, but there could be quite a few applications that can do this -- for example, if we have a gmail application, hotmail application, etc.  So, basically you're just specifying a general action and asking the system "who can handle this", and the system will handle the rest.  These types of intents are used by application developers so they don't have to "reinvent the wheel" if there is already something on the device that can do what the developer wants.

Here's a couple of references that might help explain it better:

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidIntent/article.html

Answer (score 3):

> Is this the only purpose of an explicit intent?

An `Intent` generally is used to:

- start an activity
- start or stop a service
- send a broadcast

An explicit `Intent` can be used for any of these.

> Implicit intents can also start/stop a component, but they can also be received by BroadcastReceivers.

Whether an `Intent` is implicit or explicit is independent of what sort of role the `Intent` is used for.

> Is there another way to receive an implicit intent?

An implicit `Intent` serves the roles listed above. You do not normally see it used for starting and stopping a service, though.

> When the OS sends the intent with the action set to Action.MAIN, that's an explicit intent, right?

Not necessarily. If by "the OS" you mean "the home screen", and by "sends the intent with the action set to Action.MAIN", you mean "starts an activity based upon the user tapping on an icon in the launcher", then that is an explicit `Intent`, to identify the particular activity to start. An explicit `Intent` *can* have an action string, so it is not `ACTION_MAIN` that makes the `Intent` explicit.

Comment: I don't think BroadcastReceivers can receive explicit intents

Comment: @Sarsaparilla: Fortunately, you are incorrect.

Comment: I don't think dynamically registered BroadcastReceivers can receive explicit intents

Comment: @Sarsaparilla: Explicit `Intents` are the only kind that a dynamically registered receiver can receive.

Answer (score 1):

Intent is an object which is used for communication between anyone of the android component(Activity, Services, BroadcastReceiver, ContentProvider) and Operating System.

Intent Class provides various constructors depending on what we intend to do.

In a case, Intent sends request to ActivityManager which activity to start. ActivityManager is a part of OS.

Now question will come that why do we require ActivityManager which is outside our application to communicate between two activities inside application. Here comes concept of Implicit and Explicit Intent.

Explicit Intent : To communication between components(Activity) within one application we use explicit intent.
Eg. Send current date from one activity to another.

Implicit Intent : To communicate between activities of different applications.
Eg. One application requesting photos from gallery application.

In case of Implicit Intent ActivityManager makes things easier.

Answer (score 0):

As its name suggest Intent --> It's an "intention" to do an action.

It is a way of sending a message to perform an action which can be listen by other app or O.S.

In Explicit intent you know which work to perform by which person or class.

In Implicit intent you just ask a work to do ... all the apps capable of doing the activity like sharing a message will be shown in a list and you can do your work from any one of them.